# prestashop get category product

Tags: prestashop, categories, product

I create new module

this module is add category products on home page

code is

```
public static function getproducts($id)
{
    $category = new Category($id,(int)Context::getContext()->language->id);
    $nb = 10000;
    $products = $category->getProducts((int)Context::getContext()->language->id, 1, ($nb ? $nb : 10));

    return $products;
}
```

tpl is code

```
{foreach $categories as $c}
{assign var='products' value={fhomecategory::getproducts($c.id_category)}}
{include file="$tpl_dir./product-list.tpl" products=$products class='fhome' id='fhome'}
```

{/foreach}

error -> [Click show image](https://fyazilim.com/img/hataGorseli.png)

Comment: This piece of the code is not enough to understand your issue. And there is a default Prestashop module displaying products in the home page, named "homefeatured". You can check it.

Comment: It seems that you get incorrect or an empty array of your products. And the first place where a product information is used in product-list.tpl show you the warning. Do you get anything else except the warning on your page? Try to check your $products array in product-list.tpl with {$products|@var_dump}. Would this give you something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check With Below Code:

```
$category = new Category($id, (int)Context::getContext()->language->id);
$nb = 10000;
$products = $category->getProducts((int)Context::getContext()->language->id, 1, ($nb ? $nb : 10), 'date_upd', 'DESC', false, true, true, ($nb ? $nb : 10));
```

It may be helpful.